# phone number validation not working using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi when I am clicking the register phone number is not validating because it's not calling the function.

Can any one help me from this issue

**updated post**

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" name="mobile_no" id="phone1"  onchange="return checkPhone('phone1')" class="login-input" placeholder="Mobile No"  autofocus required/>
```

**javascript**

```
function validateForm() {
 return checkPhone();
}
function checkPhone(id) {

   var phone = document.getElementById(id).value;

   var phoneNum = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

  if(phoneNum.length!=10) 
  {  
    alert("please enter 10digit mobile number");
    document.getElementById(id).value="";
  return false;  
  }
        else {
            document.getElementById("phone").className = document.getElementById("phone").className + " error";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Try using `onsubmit` on your form tag

Comment: Because form must have an `action`, so it has been submitted before js call. try use `onclick` rather than `onsubmit`.

Comment: @Sushovan it's not working

Comment: can you please provide form tag as well because it is working in my browser.

Comment: <form action="submit.php" id ="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" 
  class="login">

Comment: `<form id="myForm" action="submit.php" class="login">`  
`<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick = "return validateForm()" class="login-submit">`
this is working for me.

Comment: if i will enter 88 number not happening any yhing

Comment: Hi friends i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

use in form's onsubmit() event.
so that it will work on enter press also. 
in your case use

```
<form id ="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```